# Is there a possibility to connect to hana DB without install the hana client?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hana

I create an asp.net core webapp which fetches data via HanaConnection/HanaCommand.
If the version of the Sap.Data.Hana.vX.X.dll does not match with the installed SAP hana client, the query throws an error.

Is there a possibility to execute a query without an installed hana client?

Reason: when the client is updated on the server, the application stops working

Thanks